# получить результат работы js в другом скрипте

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть страница расширения хрома popup.html:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/store.js"></script>
```

Текст в div генерируется в popup.js

В store.js я выполняю:

```
  var theValue = $('#wrapper').text();
        console.log(theValue);
```

и получаю пустую строку(на странице она не пуста). В чем проблема?

Comment: Если Вы заполняете `div` через `ajax`, то нужно в `store.js` ожидать и поймать когда `div` заполнится.

Comment: как это реализовать?

Comment: Я бы использовал либо события, либо `MutationObserver`.

Comment: если я добавляю в div елементы постепенно как выловить именно конец работы popup.js через MutationObserver функция вызывается при каждом добавлении

Comment: Постоянно дёргать DOM - плохо, лучше добавить всё сразу. Если же нет этой возможности, ставьте флаг типа `done` и при проверке мутаций проверяйте его.

Comment: ['http://uri1.net', 'http://uri2.org'].forEach(uri => {
  fetch(uri)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(data => {
    })
});
как поймать конец работы этой функции?

Comment: Проверяйте в `data => { }` сколько готово.